# Load data from many to many related tables in one view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, many-to-many, viewmodel

I'm new to asp.net and may be missing some simple solution. So basically i've got two tables **Movie** and **Actor** here are their models:

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        this.Actors = new HashSet<Actor>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

}

public class Actor
{
    public Actor()
    {
        this.Movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to load movie details and the list of actors from the movie using ViewModel:

```
public class MovieDetailsViewModel
{
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public Actor Actor { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller for it is here:

```
 private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public MoviesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        var movie = _context.Movies.ToList();
        return View(movie);
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var movie = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        var actor = _context.Actors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == id);

        var viewModel = new MovieDetailsViewModel
        {
            Movie = movie,
            Actor = actor
        };


        if (movie == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Action **Details** is the one that needs to be loading the data that I need.
View looks something like this:

```
@model Movie_Rentals.ViewModels.MovieDetailsViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = Model.Movie.Name;
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Movie.Name</h2>
<ul>
<li>Genre: @Model.Movie.Genre</li>
<li>Release date: @Model.Movie.ReleaseDate.ToShortDateString()</li>
<li>Add date: @Model.Movie.AddDate.ToShortDateString()</li>
<li>Actors:@Model.Movie.Actors</li>
</ul>
```

And it displays **Actors:System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Movie_Rentals.Models.Actor]** which I suppose it should, but I can't mannge to find a solution on how to make it to display the actual list of actors. Does anyone have any idea on my issue, I would appreciate any help.

*P.S. I'm not a native english speaker, so sorry if my english is bad.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the Movie with all Actors using

```
_context.Movies.Include(x => x.Actors).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

Then in the View

```
@foreach (var x in Model.Movie.Actors)
    {<li>x.Name</li>}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wish I used stackoverflow earlier, it could save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

in your view you could try:

```cs
<li>Actors: @string.Join("," Model.Movie.Actors.Select(a => a.Name).ToList())</li>
```

In this way, you will show a list of actors' names associated with the movie you added to your view model.

But I would suggest you refactor your view model to include a List of actors' names, so you would remove the logic from your view. After that, your view should look like:

```cs
public class MovieDetailsViewModel
{
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public List<string> ActorsNames { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you should do:

```cs
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var movie = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

    var viewModel = new MovieDetailsViewModel
    {
        Movie = movie,
        ActorsNames = string.Join(",", movie.Actors.Select(a => a.Name).ToList())
    };

    if (movie == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

As you can see, I have removed the code where you get a single actor from the Actors DbSet because it isn't useful. Indeed, you want the full list of all actors that have appeared in the movie you get from the Movies DbSet, not just an actor that has the same id of the movie of which you have to load the details.

Also, be sure to have activated lazy loading to get the collection of actors associated with the movie, otherwise, you will get an empty collection.

Let me know if my suggestions will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To allow for the Actors field to show, you can handle this in a few ways. The easiest solution would be to add a property that parses the Actors collection into a string. You could also write code directly into the View to loop over each actor in the collection.

Example:

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        this.Actors = new HashSet<Actor>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

    public string ActorsToString
    {
        get
        {
            string _resultSet = "";
            if (Actors != null && Actors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Actor _actor in Actors)
                {
                    _resultSet += $"{_actor.Name}, ";
                }
            }
            return _resultSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest not to put your displaying logic (UI Layer) in the DB Model (Data Access Layer).